# How do I stop app returning to root view when using NavigationLinks in a TabView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I use a NavigationLink that is a child view inside a TabView, then go off the app (or in other cases change tab bar - separate tab view) then return to the app, I am back at the root view. I want to change this behaviour. I do not want to be back at the root view.

How can I stop this?

Here is a project that demonstrates my issue. Run the code in a similar, then tap a NavigationLink then go off the app and back on the app, you will be back at the root view. I want the app to remain where it was.

Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}


struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selectedCategory: TestCategory = .view1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Picker("Select View", selection: $selectedCategory) {
                    Text("View 1").tag(TestCategory.view1)
                    Text("View 2").tag(TestCategory.view2)
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding()
                
                TabView(selection: $selectedCategory) {
                    View1()
                        .tag(TestCategory.view1)
                    
                    View2()
                        .tag(TestCategory.view2)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Switch Views")
            }
        }
    }
}


enum TestCategory {
    case view1
    case view2
}

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination View1")) {
                Text("View 1 Navigation")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination View2")) {
                Text("View 2 Navigation")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `TabView` should always be on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view hierarchy seem wrong. It should be:

```
                    TabView
                  /         \
       NavigationStack    NavigationStack
              |                  |
            View1()            View2()
```

Try to re-arrange like this, and the issue could disappear.

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selectedCategory: TestCategory = .view1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedCategory) {
            View1(selectedCategory: $selectedCategory)
                .tag(TestCategory.view1)

            View2(selectedCategory: $selectedCategory)
                .tag(TestCategory.view2)
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @Binding var selectedCategory: TestCategory

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
           VStack {
               Picker("Select View", selection: $selectedCategory) {
                   Text("View 1").tag(TestCategory.view1)
                   Text("View 2").tag(TestCategory.view2)
               }
               .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
               .padding()
               ...
           }
        }
    }
}
//The same with View2
```